# How to verify which line in /etc/mtab is not in use

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

How to verify which line in /etc/mtab ia not in use

I will explain

Some times on my linux servers some command are hung 
As **df –k**

So I Suspected on /etc/mtab file , and maybe some line is stuck the machine “**df –k** hung”

But **/etc/fstab** have many lines and not clearly for me which line I need to remove
What the simple way to identify this

Answer (score 0):

You probably have NFS mounts, and the NFS server is not responding. Typically if `df` hangs, then the next unlisted filesystem in order of `/proc/mounts` (not `/etc/mtab`!) is the culprit.

If this is a frequent occurance then it may be better to mount the NFS filesystem with the `soft,intr` options, so that you can stop the hanging process with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>.